# Script to add users of particular AD OU to another AD group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

**Running Powershell as an admin**

I would like to have a script that I can run daily to add users from "cn=users,dc=costco,dc=com" to an AD group "groupname" "CN=groupname,OU=Groups,DC=costco,DC=com"

```
$When = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date
Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'cn=users,dc=costco,dc=com' -Filter { whenCreated -ge $When } | add-adgroupmember -MemberOf 'groupname'
```

it errors out with

> Add-ADGroupMember : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter
>   name 'MemberOf'. At line:2 char:111
>   + ... ilter { whenCreated -ge $When } | add-adgroupmember -MemberOf 'groupname ...
>   +                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

I have also tried with the help of a redditor

```
When = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date
Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'CN=users,dc=costo,dc=com' -Filter { whenCreated -ge $When } | ForEach-Object { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity 'Groupname' -Members $_ }
```

Error:

> Add-ADGroupMember : Insufficient access rights to perform the
>   operation At line:2 char:109
>   + ... ach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity ‘groupname’ -Members $_ } ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (groupname:ADGroup) [Add-ADGroupMember], ADException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8344,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGroupMember

Comment: The [Add-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps) does not have a parameter called `MemberOf`. As for the second error: you should be running this as a user with AD permissions to add users to a AD group. It seems you do not have that permission. 'Run as Admin' does not help, because the local administrator is still not a user with these AD permissions..

Comment: Thank you for your response, If I would like to fix the first command, which parameter should I use?

Comment: The first command is wrong. As the docs state, you cannot pass user, computer, or group objects through the pipeline to this cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

To make your first example work, you need to supply the pipeline value to the command, instead of trying to pass it in on the actual pipeline.

Try:

```
$group = "NewUsers"    
Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'cn=users,dc=costco,dc=com' -Filter { whenCreated -ge $When } | %{ Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $_.samaccountname }
```